# Scroller in the first accordion item in Flex does not appear

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have created an accordion to store images on categories. Everything is ok when I add a new element to an item, the scroller appears. The image address is saved in an txt file. However, when I open the application again the scroller does not appear. This is strange as it happens only in the first item of the accordion. If I add more elements to the other items (from the second further) everything works alright. 
Does anybody have any idea why??

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your code. 
Sample of using accordion with images inside which you can try 
(scrollbars are visible for both tabs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <mx:Accordion height="500"
                  width="100%">
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 1"
                            height="100%"
                            width="100%">
            <s:Scroller height="100%"
                        width="100%">
                <s:Group>
                    <s:Image source="http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg"/>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Scroller>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 2"
                            height="100%"
                            width="100%">
            <s:Scroller height="100%"
                        width="100%">
                <s:Group>
                    <s:Image source="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-07.jpg"/>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Scroller>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

    </mx:Accordion>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordion just write resizetocontent = true; It will work

Hope it will help

Comment: I tried it but now the scroller doesn't appear even when I add the picture and not only in the first item but in every item. It is strange, isn't it? Do you have any other idea?